# Enable webhooks in hangout chat room

Tags: webhooks, google-hangouts

I want to create a simple webhook to a chat room in chat.google.com. I am unable to see menu option to configure webhooks. What do GSuite admins have to do to enable webhooks?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/webhooks), specially the part about [limitations](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/webhooks#limitations).